# How to make a MongoDB query sort on strings with -number postfix?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a query:

```
ownUnnamedPages = Entries.find( { author : this.userId, title : {$regex: /^unnamed-/ }}, {sort: { title: 1 }}).fetch()
```

That returns the following array sorted:

```
[ { 
    title: 'unnamed-1',
    text: '<p>sdaasdasdasd</p>',
    tags: [],
    _id: 'Wkxxpapm8bbiq59ig',
    author: 'AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu',
    visibility: 'public' },
{ 
    title: 'unnamed-10',
    text: '',
    author: 'AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu',
    visibility: 'public',
    _id: 'aDSN2XFjQPh9HPu4c' },
{ 
    title: 'unnamed-2',
    text: '<p>kkhjk</p>',
    tags: [],
    _id: 'iM9FMCsyzehQvYGKj',
    author: 'AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu',
    visibility: 'public' },
{ 
    title: 'unnamed-3',
    text: '',
    tags: [],
    _id: 'zK2w9MEQGnwsm3Cqh',
    author: 'AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu',
    visibility: 'public' }]
```

The problem is that it seems to sort on the first numeric character so it thinks the proper sequence is 1, 10, 2, 3, etc....
what I really want is for it to sort on both the whole numerical part so that 10 would be at the end.

I'd prefer not to do this by having additional numbers such as 01 or 001 for the numbers.

How would I do that?

Comment: It seems the voted answer is incorrect, so you can undo accept this

Comment: Please accept the current correct answer, which is @Eugene's. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MongoDB can't sort by numbers stored as strings.  You either have to store the number as an integer in its own field, pad with leading zeroes, or sort the results after they've been returned from the database.

Comment: I wish mongodb could sort numbers stored as strings :(

Comment: db.collectionName.find().sort({title: 1}).collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})

Comment: @DavidAnderton There is check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398205/6556397)

Comment: Hey @Leopd, your response doesn't seem to be correct anymore. As @Eugene correctly noted, this can be done using `collation` and passing the `numbericOrdering` parameter. I'd usually downvote such a misleading answer, but it contains the correct answer in the comments :)

Answer (score 28):

You can use

```
db.collectionName.find().sort({title: 1}).collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})
```

numericOrdering flag is boolean and is Optional. Flag that determines whether to compare numeric strings as numbers or as strings.
If true, compare as numbers; i.e. "10" is greater than "2".
If false, compare as strings; i.e. "10" is less than "2".
Default is false.

See mongo's [collation documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/collation/#collation) for an updated explanation of those fields.

Comment: Can confirm still works as of June 2020. I had a decimal value stored in the DB as a string and it arranges them accordingly.

Comment: This is the correct answer. (july 2020, mongodb 4.0.19)

Comment: See [mongo's collation documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation) for an updated explanation of those fields.

Comment: Not that using collation like this will likely mean you will not use indexes, so this is only suitable for small collections

Answer (score 6):

If you 0 pad the numbers you will be able to search as a string in the right order, so instead of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...
use 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11...
and a string search will return them in order.

Comment: thats very interesting! can you elaborate how that works? i'm willing to try. \o/

Comment: string are sorted in ascii order, so it goes 1, 10, 2, 3... to sort strings in numeric order, you need to zero pad the string so it ends up in the ascii order 01, 02, 03,...,10

Comment: obviously, you need to pad with enough 0's to cover the full range of integrr you will use, because 100 is still going to come before 20 if you only zero pad to 2 digits. 01, 02...,10...100, 20 needs to be padded as 001, 002, 003,... 010, ... 020, ..., 100...

Answer (score 5):

The mongo documentation said you can use Collation for this goal
as @Eugene Kaurov said you can use

```
.collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})
```

this is the official documentation:
[mongo ref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/)

and be aware that the accepted answer is not correct now

Answer (score 0):

In mongo is not possible (sort strings in ascii) but you can sort with the below function after you get all documents from the collection

```
const sortString = (a, b) => {
  const AA = a.title.split('-');
  const BB = b.title.split('-');

  if (parseInt(AA[1], 10) === parseInt(BB[1], 10)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (parseInt(AA[1], 10) < parseInt(BB[1], 10)) ? -1 : 1;
};

document.sort(sortString);
```

Comment: A regular expression might be more appropriate than creating an array only to use the `1`st index from it.

Comment: @JasperdenHartog There is check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398205/6556397)

Answer (score 0):

In my case we work with aggregations. The approach was to sort using the length of our string; only works when the text part is always the same (unnamed- in your case)

```
db.YourCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "TitleSize": { $strLenCP: "$Title" }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "TitleIdSize": 1,
      "Title": 1
    }
  }
]);
```

Now we sort using length, the second sort will use the content.

Example:

- "unnamed-2", Titlesize: 9
- "unnamed-7", Titlesize: 9
- "unnamed-30", Titlesize: 10
- "unnamed-1", Titlesize: 9

The first sort will put the ids in this order: **2**, **7**, **1**, **30**. Then the second sort will put the ids in the correct order: **1**, **2**, **7**, **30**.

Comment: Know this is an old question but can be helpful. If someone can test in a .find() function will be nice.